# How can we use arrays and for loops to print out user input in rows and columns?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am supposed to create a horizontal bar graph based on the users input. I was able to do everything except figure out a way to print out the bars vertically instead of horizontally. For example, my current code print this out;
if the user input was 4, 2, 1

OOOO

OO

O

But I want it to print out:

OOO

OO

O

O

```
    //Variables

    int bar;

    String sym = "[]";

    //User input
    System.out.print("Enter the # of bars for your graph: ");
    bar = input.nextInt();
    
    //Array Initalization 
    int val [] = new int [bar];
    
     //Loop for user input (values)
    for (int x=0; x<val.length; x++) {
      System.out.print ("\nEnter the value for bar #" + (x+1) + ": ");
      val[x] = input.nextInt();
      
    }//end of for loop
    
    //loop to print out bar graph
    for (int x=0; x<val.length; x++) {
      System.out.print("\n");
      //for loop to print symbols
      for (int z=0; z<val[x]; z++) {
        System.out.print(sym);
        
      }//end of second for loop 
    
    }//end of first for loop
```

Comment: Your example code isn't complete and is this JS?

Comment: It is complete, for some reason the variables isn't showing up as code but they are listed at the top :) and yes it is javascript

Comment: @AfifaSiddiqua i think you are confusing javascript with java.